# Map 1 to1 relationship with Fluent EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I was hoping this would be fairly straight forward but I haven't had much luck. The database I'm working with has a table for users and a table for tokens, they relate to one another with a 1 to 1 relationship with tokens being as I understand it the *principal*.

```
public class Token
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public virtual User Contact { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int TokenID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Token Token { get; set; }
}
```

So every User has an associated Token which belongs to that User only, and there also also other Tokens that relate to other objects which I will be mapping as well in a similar fashion.

So far I have tried below as well as some variations and it hasn't worked as expected, I keep getting incorrect locations for users as it seems to be using User.ID to map to Token.ID instead of using User.TokenID.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.Token)
    .WithOptional(p => p.Contact);
```

I'm thinking I'm missing actually specifying the columns to use to map? I'm just unsure where to go from here.

**Edit** Previously when mapping relationships that use the WithRequired() extension method I've then been able to specify HasForeignKey() afterwards but WithOptional() doesn't seem to have this functionality.

Comment: If they're 1-1, I think EF expects them to share a primary key.

Comment: Perhaps I phrased my question incorrectly, the relationship is such that each User has a required TokenID, but Tokens may be associated with other Objects not just Users. Does this make it a "1 to 0 or 1"? If so how would I map that correctly?

Comment: yeah, if a Token doesn't have to have a User it's a 1-0:1 relationship.  This might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021135/ef-code-first-1-to-1-optional-relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution that isn't ideal, but it is working OK for me at the moment.

I have changed the models and mappings as detailed below, specifying a 1 to many relationship even though that isn't really the case.

```
public class Token
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public virtual List<User> Contact { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int TokenID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Token Token { get; set; }
}
```

Then this mapping.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasRequired(u => u.Token)
    .WithMany(t => t.Contact)
    .HasForeignKey(u => u.TokenID);
```