# Insert dependent entity with ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have the following entities:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    ...
    public int? StudentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to create an new application user and student, so I'm doing this:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() {
    Name = "test",
    UserName = "test",
    Student = new Student ()
};

var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "test12345!");
```

Result is success, the two entities are inserted in database, but Student.UserId is null

How can I insert both entities and their relationship?

I tried setting student.UserId = user.Id, but then I get an exception with this message: "Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations"

Comment: how are these mapped? Student.UserId can't be the same as User.Id (I assume) because UserId is a string type and when Id is database generated, it has to be a numeric value. edit: when user.Id is indeed a string value, the arising error can be fixed with using HasOptional().WithOptionalDependant()

Comment: Yes, Student.UserId is the same as User.Id, ApplicationUser inherits from IdentityUser, and IdentityUser by default has a string Id

Comment: Also, the model is created correctly, in database I have the correct foreign keys, it's just that the value is not set

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem and a solution are provided here [One-to-one relationsip with optional dependent end using default conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27875390/one-to-one-relationsip-with-optional-dependent-end-using-default-conventions?lq=1) and here [EF Code First - 1-to-1 Optional Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021135/ef-code-first-1-to-1-optional-relationship/6023998#6023998). But let me add something to the subject.

Your entity design creates redundancy in the `ApplicationUser` related db table, but more importantly, it creates a **foreign key relation cycle** between the two tables. Although it's technically possible to handle such a relationship, it's a maintenance nightmare and simply should be avoided.

The beauty of the EF code first approach is that you don't have to think about such things. Don't try to design your POCOs like db tables. Except for the primary key, don't use xxxId properties. Use properly configured **navigation properties** to express the relations between your entities and let EF take care of the db design.

With all that in mind:

First, remove `StudentId` property from the `ApplicationUser` class and `UserId` property from the `Student` class. Note that this will remove the `StudentId` column from the corresponding db table, so you might consider starting off with a new db or use migrations.

Then use the following configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasOptional(u => u.Student)
    .WithRequired(s => s.User).Map(a => a.MapKey("UserId"));
```

and your problem should be solved.

Comment: This one did work, I have another question, this can only be accomplished with Fluent API or is there any way I can do the same with Data Annotations?

Comment: AFAIK, Fluent API only.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for One to (zero or one) kind of relationship between student and application user. So for one user there may or may not be a student.

In that case you do not need application user Id in student class or if you want that then that will be your base class.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>() 
.HasKey(t => t.StudentId); 


// Map one-to-zero or one relationship 
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>() 
    .HasRequired(t => t.Student) 
    .WithOptional(t => t.ApplicationUser);
```

Instead if you are looking for one to one relationship

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>() 
    .HasKey(t => t.StudentId); 

modelBuilder.Entity<Instructor>() 
    .HasRequired(t => t.Student) 
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.ApplicationUser);
```

In both the cases you may not need Id on both entities. As an end note please share the mapping class for both if possible.

Comment: I've tried with both ways, the database structure seems to be ok, but when I add a Student to an ApplicationUser, and try to add it to the dbcontext, it says UserId field (in student) is required.